# How to include youtube login in an asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to include a youtube login system just like facebook has "login with facebook". I searched the api but couldn't find anything. Can someone guide me through or post link to any tutorial on how to do that.  Actually, our website gives the option to upload youtube videos(video's html embed code), but to verify that the uploader is actually the original uploader and is not uploading someone else video, we want that he login the website using youtube login and then we verify that the uploader's name and the video's uploader name are same. I have got no ideas on how to do this, can someone point me to the right direction on how to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube uses Google accounts, so you actually want a "Log in using Google". There are some docs at https://developers.google.com/accounts/.

Comment: I have changed the question. Can you please have a look and help me out here.